how to simulate and android device in selenium python
Well I have been using these chrome options to simulate android in selenium, but for some reason when i check the website results it shows os:android but when it comes to device:unknown. There are devices such as mobile and pc listed there but this does not work
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException, NoSuchElementException, ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
import time
from lolo import acpw, bcacpw, strlist, playlists
from selenium import webdriver
import random
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import names

passw = """Beliver123@"""
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

options = ChromeOptions()


mobile_emulation = {
    "deviceName": "iPhone 12 Pro",
    "deviceMetrics": {"mobile": True ,"touch": True, "width": 360, "height": 640, "pixelRatio": 3.0},

    "clientHints": {"platform": "ios", "mobile": True},

"capabilities": [
                    "touch",
                    "mobile"
                ],
}

options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
options.add_argument("disable-infobars");
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
# options.add_argument('--headless=new')
# options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')


for i in acpw:
    globals()[f"driver{i}"] = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
globals()[f"driver{i}"].get(<cant name the website sorry!>)


i tried using useragebt string but it stil does not work

it would be simpler to use list drivers = [] and later drivers.append( ... ) to add element and drivers[i].get(...) to use it - instead of using variables driver1, driver2 and globals()[f"driver{i}"]. OR you can use dictionary drivers = {} and later use drivers[f"driver{i}"] without using global()
